# Having Tabs in Xcode?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, xcode

Can someone tell me how to make sure that when I open multiple files (i.e., `xed blah1.c`, `xed blah2.c`, and so on) from the Terminal that they open as different tabs and not as different windows? I am using Lion.

Answer (score 1):

XCode doesn't have tabs in the traditional sense like your browser, Eclipse and Visual Studios.

The closest tool would be the Favorites bar. You can also switch between open windows using CMD+Tab.

**edit**

The favorites bar is the area one the document window that you can drag files to. It's essentially like your bookmark bar on the browser.

[image]

Comment: But then again command -tab would switch between all open applications and not just the code files that I am interested in .Could you tell me about favorites bar? I am willing to switch to any other GUI based editor for MAC.Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @surfasb Command-Tab switches between apps: Command-` switches between an app's windows.

Comment: @CajunLuke - Ahh yes!